# Missing return statement even though my loop has if and else

Tags: java, loops

I have a method that contains both an if and an else statement with returns and it's still saying it is missing a return statement

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str){    
    int n = str.length();
    for( int i = 0; i < n/2; i++ ){
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n-i-1)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;  
        }
    }
}
```

Not really sure what to do here, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To find this kind of compilation error, you need to follow all paths through the method.

In this case, if `n` is zero (for a zero-length string), the for loop is never entered, and therefore there is no return statement:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str){  // when str = ""    
    int n = str.length();                 // n = 0
    for( int i = 0; i < 0; i++ ){         // never enters the loop
                                          // no code executed in here
    }
                                          // return statement is missing here
}
```

It seems (as @ElliotFrisch pointed out) that you probably want the `return true;` statement outside the for loop rather than in the else block.

Answer (score 2):

You can't immediately return in your `else` (because you'll only check the first character). You need something like,

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**or**

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().equals(str);
}
```

**or** if you're using Java 8+ with an `IntStream` and `allMatch` like

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length() / 2) //
            .allMatch(i -> str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1));
}
```

**or**

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return IntStream.range(0, str.length() / 2) //
            .noneMatch(i -> str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove else. do it like that:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str){    
int n = str.length();
for( int i = 0; i < n/2; i++ ){
    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n-i-1)){
        return false;
    }
   }
        return true;  

    }
```

because if the statement inside the if not true it will go outside and just return the value that is not apply the condition.